# missing lboost_thread-mt in mongodb cpp driver (ubuntu server x64)

Tags: c++, linux, mongodb, ubuntu, linker

i have a brand new ubuntu server x64.

i installed the following packages

build-essential

libboost-all-dev

mongodb-dev

mongodb-10gen

now when i try to compile the example code i get this error.

root@server:/home/user/Desktop# g++ mongotest.cpp -pthread -lmongoclient -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_filesystem -lboost_program_options -lboost_system -o tutorial

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_thread-mt

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

i searched everywhere i can think of and in every way i can think of but it doesn't work.

UPDATE:
like vershov said it works with the lboost_thread but it needs lssl and lcrypto to compile

the final command that worked for me is:

g++ mongoc.cpp -pthread -lmongoclient -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem -lboost_program_options -lboost_system -lssl -lcrypto -o tutorial

thank you vershov!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/i386/libboost-thread1.54-dev/filelist shows that Ubuntu libboost-thread package has **libboost_thread.so** library file, not **libboost_thread-mt.so**

So, correct command is:

root@server:/home/user/Desktop# g++ mongotest.cpp -pthread -lmongoclient -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem -lboost_program_options -lboost_system -o tutorial

Comment: tried it, no go. In function `mongo::SSLManager::cleanupThreadLocals()':
(.text+0x393): undefined reference to `ERR_remove_state'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libmongoclient.a(ssl_manager.o): In function `boost::thread_specific_ptr<mongo::SSLThreadInfo>::delete_data::operator()(void*)':
(.text._ZN5boost19thread_specific_ptrIN5mongo13SSLThreadInfoEE11delete_dataclEPv[_ZN5boost19thread_specific_ptrIN5mongo13SSLThreadInfoEE11delete_dataclEPv]+0xc): undefined reference to `CRYPTO_set_id_callback'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: It's definitely another issue, you need to link your program with the crypto and openssl libraries.